# AngularJS recursive ng-repeat variable binding with ng-include

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, recursion

I'm having a problem while programming a dynamic structure with AngularJS. I have basically a tree structure, which can go potentially down recursively to infinity. I need to build an HTML page according to this tree, where every node of the tree needs to be displayed by a specific HTML template, according to its type. By using `ng-repeat` and `ng-include` I can do this quite easily, apart from the fact that problems related to the variable binding arise.
To better explain the situation, I'll use a simplified example.
This is my controller:

```
function testController($scope,$http,$timeout,$window,$state, Data) {
  $scope.blocks = []

  block1 = {
    "type":"block",
    "id":1,
    "innerblocks":[],
    "html":"block1.html"
  }

  block21 = {
    "type":"block",
    "id":21,
    "innerblocks":[],
    "html":"block2.html"
  }
  block22 = {
    "type":"block",
    "id":22,
    "innerblocks":[],
    "html":"block2.html"
  }

  block1.innerblocks.push(block21);
  block1.innerblocks.push(block22);

  $scope.showFromBlock1 = function () {
    $scope.blocks = [];
    $scope.blocks.push(block1);
  }

  $scope.showFromBlock2 = function () {
    $scope.blocks = [];
    $scope.blocks.push(block21);
    $scope.blocks.push(block22);
  }
}
```

where `$scope.blocks` represents the root of my tree, which has 1 inner node (block1) and 2 leafs (block21 and block22).

`index.html` is:

```
<!-- all the necessary tags and includes -->
<body ng-controller="testController">

    <button ng-click="showFromBlock1()" >From Block1</button>
    <button ng-click="showFromBlock2()" >From Block2</button>

    <div ng-repeat="block in blocks">
        <div ng-include="block.html">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

whereas my templates are:
`block1.html`

```
<div>
  <div>
    BLOCK 1 TYPE: {{block.id}}
    <div ng-repeat="innerblock in block.innerblocks">
        <div ng-include="innerblock.html">
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

`block2.html`

```
<div>
   <div>
      BLOCK 2 TYPE: {{block.id}}
   </div>
</div>`
```

As you can see if you run this example, when "From Block2" is pressed (meaning that the html should display the tree starting from blocks on level 2), the ids are displayed correctly, as the `block` variable in the `index` is bound correctly to the one in `block2.html`. If you press instead "From Block1", you will see that the `block` variable inside `block2.html` is bound again the one in `index.html`, instead of being bound to the `innerblock` variable in `block1.html`, displaying thus the "wrong" id. I understand that this is due to the naming, but how can I manage these recursive situations, when there are templates that can be nested on into another, an they should use a general variable name? 
(of course, this is a small example of something that might be much more complex)

Comment: You should create a directive or a component. That way you can isolate the scope of the variables with their own templates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working a little bit I found my solution. It is enough to use `ng-init` in every `ng-include` inside a `ng-repeat` to re-bind the loop variable. According to this, the repeat in `index.html` will look like

```
<div ng-repeat="block in blocks">
    <div ng-include="block.html" ng-init="block = block">
    </div>
</div>
```

while the one in `block1.html` will be

```
<div ng-repeat="innerblock in block.innerblocks">
    <div ng-include="innerblock.html" ng-init="block = innerblock">
    </div>
</div>`
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `ng-include` create a directive with the isolated scope that will use templates from your blocks. This way you'll be able to use generic naming without any conflicts.